# Get the bit.ly link on the page to which bit.ly link redirects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, google-analytics, hyperlink, bit.ly

How could I get the `bit.ly` link on the page to which `bit.ly` link redirects using JavaScript?

I need this for tracking purposes. I have a few `bit.ly` links and I would like to track how many times each one of them was clicked in GA.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't know what page `bit.ly/something` redirects to without making the round trip yourself.  Why don't you track the original urls instead?

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara, Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages.

Comment: @James, I am interested in how many people will follow the link after they got it in SMS. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the tutorials on using bit.ly with google analytics?  [example](https://www.morevisibility.com/blogs/analytics/tracking-bitly-and-other-short-urls-in-google-analytics.html).  Basically you would have to set up tracking on the destination site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following if you insist on working with Javascript.

Send the bit.ly link as a GET parameter with the destination URL. For example:
Change this

```
<a href="receiver.html">bit.ly/link_1</a>
```

to

```
<a href="receiver.html?sending_url="bit.ly/link_1">bit.ly/link_1</a>
```

Then in receiver.html use

```
location.search
```

property to get the list of parameters. Parse this to extract the url that was clicked. One way to do so is to use regular expressions in Javascript. This tutorial is a good starting point https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

However, the above technique is a hack and not the correct way to send and receive data across pages. Javascript is a client-side language. A much easier and appropriate way would be to use a server-side language such as PHP to process the sent data.

Comment: The `bit.ly` link is going to be embedded as a plain text into an SMS, there is not `<a>` tag here. Thank you.